# Putting a tabular in a node within a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, matrices, nodes

I have a picture in which each of the nodes looks something like this:

```
\node (species1) [shape=rectangle,draw] {
  \begin{tabular}{c c c}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{{Species 1}} \\
  \colorbox{red}{G1a} & \colorbox{blue}{G2a} &
  \colorbox{green}{G3} \\
  \colorbox{blue}{G1b} & \colorbox{red}{G2b} & 
  \end{tabular}
};
```

The nodes look fine, but when I put them all into a `matrix` node to align them properly, the `tabular`s inside the nodes are all screwed up and I get errors like this one:

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. ...{G1} & \colorbox{blue}{G2a} &
\colorbox (followed by: {green!50}{G3})
```

Is there are way to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried to surround the node contents with `{}`? (ie. `{ \begin{tabular}...` and `...\end{tabular} }`)

Comment: @morbusg: Just tried it and it does not change anything.

Comment: make a complete example. Inside a tikzpicture environment it works.

Comment: @Herbert: not in a matrix within a tikzpicture.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that TikZ needs to make `&` equivalent to `\pgfmatrixnextcell`, which interferes with the normal functioning of `&` as a table cell separation marker. Fortunately, TikZ includes the `ampersand replacement` option that lets you choose any other macro for matrix cell separation instead of `&`. The following example uses `\&` as replacement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[ampersand replacement=\&] {
        \node (species1) [shape=rectangle,draw] {
            \begin{tabular}{c c c}
                \multicolumn{3}{c}{{Species 1}} \\
                \colorbox{red}{G1a} & \colorbox{blue}{G2a} & \colorbox{green}{G3} \\
                \colorbox{blue}{G1b} & \colorbox{red}{G2b} & 
            \end{tabular}
        };
        \& 
        \node {b}; \\
        \node {c}; \& \node {d}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can put each node inside a save box, and then it will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newsavebox{\speciesone}
\sbox{\speciesone}{
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{{Species 1}} \tabularnewline
  \colorbox{red}{G1a} & \colorbox{blue}{G2a} &
  \colorbox{green}{G3} \tabularnewline
  \colorbox{blue}{G1b} & \colorbox{red}{G2b} & 
  \end{tabular}
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes] {
\node (species1) [shape=rectangle,draw] {\usebox{\speciesone}};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```