# How would you set a table inside a Circuitikz enviroment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, circuitikz

How do I insert a table into a circuit using CircuiTikz and using absolute coordinates?

I would like to know if there is a way to insert a table that is written with `\tabular` into the CircuiTikz enviroment.

The red circle is where I would like to instert the table:

[image]

I do not show you the code because is up to 240 lines.

Comment: `\node at (<x>,<y>) {\begin{tabular}{<cols>}<table>\end{tabular}};`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401264/how-to-insert-a-table-in-tikzedt-create-tikz-diagrams-with-tables-using-a-gui

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9301/nesting-a-tikz-picture-and-tabular-within-an-array-environment

Comment: A runnable M.W.E. of a part of that picture, say "7476", would be nice ;)

Comment: Why? Do you need any of that? In that case this is where I learned how to do it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521798/custom-integrated-circuits-with-circuitikz

Comment: A node with a tabular is a very nice solution, like @skillmon has suggested; you can also use a TikZ `matrix` (remember, a circuitikz environment is a tikzpicture renamed...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution so far is using the comment Skillmon sugests:

```
\node at (<x>,<y>) {\begin{tabular}{<cols>}<table>\end{tabular}};
```