# Draw a picture where some parts are tables

Tags: tables

As mentioned above, like the picture below:

[image: picture with tables]

Comment: You can do that with the `psmatrix` environment, from  the `pst-node` package (a member of the `pstricks` family).

Comment: To the downvoters: Please don't downvote a question (especially if it's the first question of a new user) without leaving an explanation of why you think the question needs improvement. Just downvoting without giving the user a chance to improve their post is useless and plain hostile.

Comment: dshbusiness, welcome to Tex.SE. Probably you got downvoted because usually, asking how to draw something just supplying a picture of your desired result without posting any code attempt in your question is seen as a "gimme teh codez" request and not very well welcomed. Probably you were asking how in a "what could I use" sense and that's a more valid question. You can ask what packages are best suited for a certain task. In any case, adding some wording to your question to make this explicit is the best bet.

Comment: By the way, you can still edit your question (and downvotes might be retracted in that case).

Comment: Alternatively, you could post some code e.g. for the individual parts of the picture and ask for help putting them together to form the whole diagram. If the question is which packages you could use: you could use `tikz` as an alternative to `pstricks`. TikZ also has libraries for matrices and so on. Or you could create the individual elements and then use `tikzmark` to annotate them and add the arrows etc.

Comment: @dshbusiness Look at both answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9244/putting-a-tabular-in-a-node-within-a-matrix.  This will show you how to put a tabular inside of a node.  There are two separate techniques demonstrated and they both work quite well.

Comment: The tables don't really make a difference to the difficulty of the drawing - just treat them as labels and use `tabular` to make them.  TikZ, pstricks, Asymptote or Metapost are all suitable.

Answer (score 3):

A starting point using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (ul)
  {%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    Reference paper \\
    \hline
    rp sentence1 \\
    rp sentence2 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  };
\node[below=of ul] (ml)
  {%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    Citances to rp1 \\
    \hline
    citance1 \\
    citance2 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  };
\node[below=of ml] (ll)
  {%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    Abstracts \\
    \hline
    abstract1 \\
    abstract2 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  };

\node (mm) at ([xshift=3.5cm] $ (ul.north)!0.5!(ll.south) $ )
  {%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    rp1 & $\ldots$ \\
    rp2 & $\ldots$ \\
    \hline
    c1 & $\ldots$ \\
    c2 & $\ldots$ \\
    \hline
    a1 & $\ldots$ \\
    a2 & $\ldots$ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  };
\foreach \Nodo in {ul,ml,ll}
{  \draw[->]
    (\Nodo.east) -- (mm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]